# Create new matrix of cell arrays

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a Cell Array 1x254 with data of this type:

```
data = {'15/13' '14/12' '16/13' '16/13' '16/14' '17/14' '17/14' '18/14' '19/15'};
```

the first number corresponds to the temp, the second number the temp2

I need to separate the data and insert them in a matrix :

```
B =

    15    13
    14    12
    16    13
    16    13
    16    14
    17    14
    18    14
    19    15
```

I tried to use this solution

```
data = regexp(tempr, '\W','split');
B=cell2mat(cat(3,data{:}));
```

but I find no way to get ahead....

could  give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close. You can do it using `regexp` as you did, but with `/` as the delimiter, in addition to `cellfun`(which is just a loop really) to convert from strings to digits, then apply `cell2mat` to get a numeric array as output:

```
clc
clear

data = {'15/13' '14/12' '16/13' '16/13' '16/14' '17/14' '17/14' '18/14' '19/15'};

%// Split data
C = regexp(data, '/', 'split');

%// Convert from strings to double
D = cellfun(@str2double,C,'uni',0);

%// Get final numeric matrix
E = cell2mat([D(:)])
```

NOTE:

As pointed out by Luis Mendo, `str2double` operates on cell arrays so you can trade `cellfun` and `cell2mat` for this single line:

```
E = str2double(vertcat(C{:}))
```

Output:

```
E =

    15    13
    14    12
    16    13
    16    13
    16    14
    17    14
    17    14
    18    14
    19    15
```

Comment: Great glad I could help!

Comment: `str2double` allows cell array input. So you can use `E = str2double(vertcat(C{:}));`

Comment: Oh right I keep forgetting that. I'll add it to the answer thanks!

Comment: @Luis MendoYou have always elegant solutions, thanks